# python get text between 2 strings in wordlist

Tags: python

I'm newbie in python
I have simple wordlist written in txt format

```
hello, hai, hi, halo
```

what i want, to get text between 2 strings start with word in wordlist and end with "." (dot)

The code I tried

```
import re
START = open('C:\\Users\\aaaa\\Desktop\\word.txt', 'r')

END = "\."
test = "Hello my name is aaaa."

m=re.compile('%s(.*?)%s' % (START.read(),END),re.S)
print m.search(test).group(1)
```

and it got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\pyhtonism.py", line 10, in <module>
print m.search(test).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want exactly?

Comment: what i want  print "my name is aaaa"

Comment: so you will always skip the first word in each sentence? Or you use `hello, hai, hi, halo` as the key.

Comment: yes, I want to skip first word using the key hello, hai, hi, halo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues here.

1. If you are searching for any word in a list of words, you need to put the list its own group with brackets, delimited by the pipe character. In your case this is `(hello|hai|hi|halo)` which you can achive by changing your regex to `re.compile('(%s)(.*?)%s' % (START.read().replace(', ','|'),END)`
2. You are trying to do a case insensitive search, so you have to pass the flag `IGNORECASE` like this:

   `m = re.compile('(%s)(.*?)%s' % (START.read().replace(', ','|'),END), flags = re.IGNORECASE)`

Note that after this change you need to change to `group(2)` since the first group is now 'hello'.